# Can't seem to connect to my MySQL database via c#

Tags: c#, mysql

like the title says, I cannot connect to my database via c#, I get the following exception when I try to open an connection:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

But I can connect no problem with PHP using the exact same login info.

**EDIT** I am just changing databases. This connection string has worked for 2 years using a different database. I have tried it using Server, instead of Data Source, and UID/User ID instead of UserID with the same result

C#:

```
ProjectDBC = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=combinedsystems.ca;Database=combined_project;UserID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;");
```

PHP:

```
$db_user = "xxxxx";
$db_pass = "xxxxx";
$db_database = "combined_project"; 
$db_host = "combinedsystems.ca";

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);
```

It is probably something easy, but I just can't figure it out right now. Any ideas?

The database is hosted through hosteasysolutions.com if that makes any difference

Comment: is that instance set up to allow tcp connections? are all the firewalls in between configured to allow the traffic?

Comment: Uhhh, I am not sure about either of those...how do I check?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string looks wrong... You need to specify `Server`, `Uid` and `Pwd` instead of `Data Source`, `UserID` and `Password`, or specify `Data Source`, `User ID` and `Password` (User ID has a space)

```
Server=combinedsystems.ca;Database=combined_project;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;
```

OR

```
Data Source=combinedsystems.ca;Database=combined_project;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;
```

Check [this link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for examples.

Comment: I don't - but I have used it this exact same way for ever. I am just changing my program to use a different database now, the string that I am using has worked for the other database...wierd

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your login credentials are correct for the new database? Does the user have access to the new database?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a server, do you? I use following string to connect to mysql hosts:

```
Server=localhost;Database=db;UID=user;Password=pass
```

Comment: I don't - but I have used it this exact same way for ever. I am just changing my program to use a different database now, the string that I am using has worked for the other database...wierd

Answer (score 1):

Try using a space between User and ID or just use User= or UID=

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you don't have (somehow - somewhere) two connection strings defined in your project since you were changing database!!!